# Spark: writing to kafka gives error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic RANDOM_STRING not present in metadata after 60000 ms

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a pyspark streaming code that reads from socket, and writes to Kafka topic.
When I am writing to console its able to print it out, but when i am writing to Kafka topic, its giving me `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic RANDOM_STRING not present in metadata after 60000 ms.`
The log is:

```
2022-12-13 09:18:22,631 - my_module_lib_io.streaming.kafka.spark.producer - INFO - Open Socket on localhost 9999 by using command on another shell: nc -l localhost 9999
22/12/13 09:18:22 WARN sources.TextSocketSourceProvider: The socket source should not be used for production applications! It does not support recovery.
22/12/13 09:18:25 WARN sources.TextSocketSourceProvider: The socket source should not be used for production applications! It does not support recovery.
[Stage 1:>                                                          (0 + 3) / 3]
22/12/13 09:19:34 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, server.com, executor 1): org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic RANDOM_STRING not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

I am running this **Apache Kafka (kafka_2.11-2.0.0)** as **localhost:9092**, with no SSL enabled. **server.properties** looks:

```
broker.id=1
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
log.dirs=/home/aiman/kafka_local/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/kafka-logs
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
max.poll.interval.ms=5
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=3
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
session.timeout.ms=3
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

The topic (RANDOM_STRING) is existing:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
TEST_TOPIC
RANDOM_STRING
__consumer_offsets
```

My Code is:

```
kafka_config = {
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
    "checkpointLocation": "/user/aiman/checkpoint/kafka_local/random_string",
    "topic": "RANDOM_STRING"
}
data = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 9999).load()
# This Print the dataframe in console:
# data.writeStream \
#     .format("console") \
#     .outputMode("append") \
#     .option("truncate", False) \
#     .start() \
#     .awaitTermination()
data.writeStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .options(**kafka_config) \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()
```

I am using the following spark-sql connector: `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.3.4.jar`
Spark version `2.4.0-cdh6.3.4`.
And Apache Kafka version is `kafka_2.11-2.0.0`.

**UPDATE:**
changed the apache kafka version to `kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0`.

Is it any configuration I am missing ?

Comment: Could you produce to this topic with cli?

Comment: yes i did using the utility shell. it writes to the topic. but from spark-streaming facing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce. Is `RANDOM` really **random**? If so, I suspect that is the problem. Otherwise, Spark is distributed, but you're referring to `localhost` for Kafka, so do you have more than one Kafka cluster, one of which doesn't have the topic you're using?

Using latest Spark (but that probably isn't your issue, although, I'd advise not using a CDH specific version), and Kafka 3.3 (again, version shouldn't really matter)

Create and check topics

```
$ kafka-topics --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 | grep RANDOM_STRING
RANDOM_STRING
```

Start a server

```
$ nc -lk 9999
```

Run the code, using a package for my Spark version. Note: master is local, rather than `yarn` in CDH

```
spark-submit --master=local --packages 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13:3.3.1' example.py
```

(type something in the `nc` teriminal)

Then consume it.

```
kcat -C -b localhost:9092 -t 'RANDOM_STRING' -o earliest
hello world
% Reached end of topic RANDOM_STRING [2] at offset 1
```

Note: Python has native libraries for TCP socket servers and Kafka producers, so if your code is just forwarding requests from one to the other, Spark is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer the reply really gave me an idea when you said `--master=local`.  Since in my case Spark is running on cluster, and Kafka on local, the executors are not getting hold of localhost.  So I configured my kafka and renamed all the "localhost" to my hostname.  Now i am able to connect.